# Simplejson dump and load not returning valid dictionary

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, simplejson

I'm trying to store a json result in the GAE datastore, so that I can read it later.  I'm dumping it to a String, then storing it, then reading it and loading it back into a dict.  But I can no longer read it as a dict after loading.

```
result = freebase.mqlready(query)
```

Print result:

```
[{u'mid': u'/m/095hd',
  u'name': u'Settlers of Catan',
  u'type': u'/games/game'},
 {u'mid': u'/m/025sm93',
  u'name': u'The Game of Life',
  u'type': u'/games/game'}]
```

```
for r in result:
    name = r.name # works, I can get the name and other values.

json_dump = simplejson.dumps(result)
text = db.Text(json_dump)
fbresult = model.FB(text=text)
fbresult.put()
####
stored_text = fbresult.text
json = simplejson.loads(stored_text)
```

Print json:

```
[{u'mid': u'/m/095hd',
  u'name': u'Settlers of Catan',
  u'type': u'/games/game'},
 {u'mid': u'/m/025sm93',
  u'name': u'The Game of Life',
  u'type': u'/games/game'}]
```

```
for j in json:
    name = json.name
```

ERROR:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Your variable name `json` clashes with the module name `json`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uh, looks like you're accessing the collection rather than the inner object:

Surely you meant:

```
for j in json:
    name = j['name']
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ordinary dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) doesn't transform attribute access into item lookup:

```
>>> d = {'name': 'Joe'}
>>> d.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'
>>> d['name']
'Joe'
```

`simplejson` returns ordinary dictionaries by default.

You could use [`Storage`](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/gluon/storage.py) object that is like a dictionary except `obj.foo` can be used
in addition to `obj['foo']`.

```
>>> from storage import Storage
>>> s = Storage(d)
>>> s['name']
'Joe'
>>> s.name
'Joe'
```

You could convert all json-objects to `Storage` using `object_hook` parameter:

```
obj = simplejson.loads(stored_text, object_hook=Storage)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `result` returned by freebase.mqlready is not a real dict but a subclass which delegates to `__getitem__` via `__getattr__` (ie: you can do `r.name` instead of `r['name']`).
simplejson can dump it just fine (it is a dict subclass) but when it loads it back it returns a plain dict instead which doesn't delegate attribute access to item access.